# AWS high availability architecture setup involving Postgress RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-elb, amazon-route53

I'm trying to setup High availability infrastructure architecture in AWS across regions serving content from 2 regions. I'm using Postgress RDS where REGION-1 has primary db in multi-AZ RDS setup. I'm trying to create another RDS in the secondary REGION. I'm only able to create a Read Replica of the primary instance in REGION-2.

The issue is --> how to setup the Secondary Postgress RDS which is under continuous replication with the Primary instance while also having write capacity such that if Region-1 fails and traffic is served from Region-2 the Secondary RDS has write capabilities and replicate the data with primary RDS once its health is restored.

In REGION-1, I have created a load-balancer with 2 webapp and 2 api instances in 2 AZ's connected to one Postgress RDS which is in Multi-AZ setup. In Region-2, load-balancer setup connecting a standby webapp and api instance connected to a secondary RDS in Region 2 (apparently this RDS only has read permissions and is under replication)

Incase of AZ failure, the multi-az setup, AWS itself handles failure of primary RDS and switches traffic to the backup instance and makes the replica instance main instance with read-write capabilities.

Incase of Multi-Region creation only creation of Read Replica is possible. Issue - incase of Regional failure there requires manual intervention where the read replica has to be converted to new standalone instance and establish connection manually increasing the RTO & RPO. How to avoid this manual intervention and make architecture intelligent enough to identify failure of primary RDS, serve content from region-2 RDS and replicate with primary RDS once its health is restored.